# Are you able to earn skins and cases in counter strike global offensive or do you have to purchase them?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

In counter strike global offensive can you earn skins and cases through grinding in the game, or must you purchase them with real world cash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it in one of two ways you can ethier one buy the skins/cases off of the steam market or two you can get case drops randomly (usually only one per week) and when you level up you get a drop (also once a week)

Comment: Bear in mind that the keys which are used to open those cases are sold via money. So you'll still need to pay real-life money in order to open a case. However, you can also accumulate that money by selling cases or skins on the market,

Answer (score -1):

All depends on luck, I once got a drop Icarus Fell, 100$ m4a1s for free...

Its just you have to be lucky :P

Same thing you can sell in the market and other users purchase it and you get the money with transaction fee charged by steam.

Comment: This adds nothing that hasn't already been said.

Comment: lul k :P, well I liked to say it again @Frank

Answer (score -2):

There is websites where you can 1v1 for skins but you shouldnt use them cause some of them arent safe and you can get banned from what i have heard